# viper-mode にて ESC と C-[ を入れ替えるには？

Tags: emacs, elisp

emacs の viper-mode において、ESC と C-[ の挙動を入れ替えたいのですが、これはどうやったら行えるでしょうか。

現状では、 ESC は挿入モードからコマンドモードへ戻る動作をしていて、C-[ はメタキーの代わり的な動作をしています。

Comment: 回避策が思い浮かばないため回答を削除しました。